# sql server tsql run powershell script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powershell

I have created a powershell script that opens an excel file, formats a column, and then resaves the excel file.  This script works from powershell and the commandline, but when run in a stored procedure (tsql) it does nothing.  No errors either.  I've tried to run the powershell script from a job agent and it ran but nothing happens.  Do I have to do something to enable powershell scripts in sql server?

Here is the code from the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @SqlPowerShell AS VARCHAR(1000)
set @SqlPowerShell = 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\temp\Script.ps1"'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @SqlPowerShell
```

Here is the powershell script:

```
#
# Script.ps1
#
#param([string]$today="0") #Must be the first statement in your script
$today=Get-Date -format Mddyyyy
$file="c:\temp\TeamCurrentStockInventory_" + $today + ".xlsx"
$xl=New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $FALSE
#$xl.Visible = $TRUE

$wb=$xl.Workbooks.Open($file)

# Open/Edit first Sheet
$ExcelWorkSheet = $xl.WorkSheets.item(1)
#Select entire column
$ExcelWorkSheet.Range("F:F").HorizontalAlignment = -4152 #right justified value

$wb.SaveAs("c:\temp\TeamCurrentStockInventory_" + $today + "_v1.xlsx")
$wb.Close()
$xl.Quit()

#Remove-Item $file

# now you only need to release two.
while([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wb)){}
while([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)){}
```

Comment: Did you install power-shell support? Have a look at [Running SQL Server PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281962.aspx)

Comment: You have excel installed on that sql box? I'm sure that would be one hurdle. I don't expect office to be installed on database servers.

Comment: office is installed.  Not sure about the powershell support.

Comment: For starters, you probably have to provide the full path to powershell.exe.  Second, you have to make sure the account that you are running under, has access to run powershell scripts, and has access to the excel file.  Third, it's probably best to create a sql agent job to execute your powershell script for you, then just call the sql agent job  via TSQL to execute it.  In the SQL Agent job, there should be option to provide account name/pwd that has the proper permissions.

Comment: I have a Sql Agent Job that calls the stored procedure.